# Rails wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method in my `groups` controller.

```
def remove
  @usergroup = Usergroup.where(group_id: params[:group_id]).destroy
  redirect_to groups_path
end
```

And

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', { controller: "groups", action: "remove" },
    group_id: @group.id, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

When I click remove and confirm the removal, I get this error.

[image]

I am a bit confused because the id of the group is 6 and it should be. For the group I am trying to remove somebody from. Why would it be giving me a no arguments error for this?

This is a route I have set. I believe this is the issue.
`get 'groups/remove/:id', to: 'groups#remove'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using `where`, and it returns a `Model::ActiveRecord_Relation`, then you need to "identify" the object you want to destroy, that's, accessing the singular element, you can do it by accessing a specific element in the result, like:

```
Usergroup.where('group_id = ?', params[:group_id]).first.destroy
```

Or to use `destroy_all`, which would take all the objects within that result and destroy all of them:

```
Usergroup.where('group_id = ?', params[:group_id]).destroy_all
```

Comment: After trying your method I seem to be getting this error: `undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: So your query using `where` has an empty result.

Comment: `.where().first` => `.find_by`

Comment: Please see updated question. I believe this has something to do with the route.

Comment: You're using `params[:group_id]`, but your route and your params say `id`, try instead using id in both cases @TrentonTyler.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but your setting a variable to something that youve destroyed

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of your use of `where`, you are trying to call destroy on a list of objects because when you call ActiveRecord `.where` it returns a list even if there is only one.  You should try to do it like this instead:

```
@group = Usergroup.find_by(group_id: params[:group_id])
if @group
  @group.destroy
...
```

and make your link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', name_of_path_here_path(group_id: @group.id), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

Also, remember that you could use the Restful routes pattern commonly used in Rails: *routes.rb* (ex: `resources :usergroups`).  You can also alias routes with the `as: :name_of_route_here`.  To double check your routes you can open up terminal and run `bundle exec rake routes` and on the left column of the routes is the name of the route helper.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your params are id =6 not group_id =6

Comment: This can be added as a comment Dave.

Comment: Yeah sorry my phone is flidding out.